# In .NET, how do I get the order of YYYY, MM and DD for a given culture

Tags: .net, date, cultureinfo

Designing a culture independent birthdate input consisting of three select: year, month and day.

In .NET, how do I get the correct display order of the three for a given culture, ie.:

```
┌─────────────┬─┐  ┌──────────────┬─┐  ┌────────────┬─┐
│ Select year │v│  │ Select month │v│  │ Select day │v│  
└─────────────┴─┘  └──────────────┴─┘  └────────────┴─┘

┌─────────────┬─┐  ┌──────────────┬─┐  ┌────────────┬─┐
│ Select day  │v│  │ Select month │v│  │ Select year│v│  
└─────────────┴─┘  └──────────────┴─┘  └────────────┴─┘
```

or

```
┌─────────────┬─┐  ┌──────────────┬─┐  ┌────────────┬─┐
│ Select month│v│  │ Select day   │v│  │ Select year│v│  
└─────────────┴─┘  └──────────────┴─┘  └────────────┴─┘
```

*** UPDATE ***
Thanks to all for your answers, it made me come up with this little function:

```
  Public Function GetDateElementAtPos(ByVal pos As Integer) As String
    Return Mid(Me.myCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Split(Me.myCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator)(pos), 1, 1).ToLower
  End Function
```

Where `myCultureInfo` represents a initialized `Globalization.CultureInfo`. I use it like this:

```
Dim s as new stringbuilder
For i As Integer = 0 To 2
  Select Case GetDateElementAtPos(i)
    Case "y"
      s.append(**year select html goes here**)
    Case "m"
      s.append(**month select html goes here**)
    Case "d"
      s.append(**day select html goes here**)
  End Select
Next
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution Muleskinner, if this is for a web application, make sure you use the CurrentUICulture though, otherwise you will return the culture of the IIS server.

Comment: @Tony Leeper Yes its for a webapp, and yes I know thanks. It is used behind user authorization and the user chose himself his culture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
CultureInfo c = ....;
var dtf = c.DateTimeFormat;
var fs = dtf.ShortDatePattern;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the CurrentUICulture.  E.g.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

Will give you the pattern, then you'll need to work out from that the display order.

Comment: Thanks, good answer - the accepted were a few minutes earlier